# cv2.imshow and write video frames in colab

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, keras, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run this https://github.com/xamyzhao/timecraft/blob/master/make_timelapse.py

and colab does not support cv2.imshow so I changed this part

```
for i in range(n_samples):
    pred_vid = video_predictor_model.predict(
        [im[np.newaxis], np.ones((1,) + im.shape), np.zeros((1, 5))])
    print(f'Predicted video shape: {pred_vid.shape}')

    pred_vid_im = vis_utils.visualize_video(
        pred_vid[0], normalized=True)

    cv2.imshow(f'Video sample {i+1}', pred_vid_im)
cv2.waitKey()
```

to

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

  for i in range(n_samples):
    pred_vid = video_predictor_model.predict(
        [im[np.newaxis], np.ones((1,) + im.shape), np.zeros((1, 5))])
    print(f'Predicted video shape: {pred_vid.shape}')

    pred_vid_im = vis_utils.visualize_video(
        pred_vid[0], normalized=True)

    #cv2.imshow(f'Video sample {i+1}', pred_vid_im)
    cv2_imshow(pred_vid_im)
    cv2.imwrite(f'Video sample {i+1}.jpg', pred_vid_im)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but saved frames are just black and Im not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a google colab issue. pred_vid_im holds the normalized value. So all the values will be between 0 and 1. That's why the saved image is black.
So you need to multiply pred_vid_im with 255.0. Change the code to this,

```
pred_vid_im = vis_utils.visualize_video(pred_vid[0], normalized=True) * 255.0
```

Now the saved image will be correct.

Comment: You're welcome. Accepting the answer would be nice.